# Extract indices of a grouped elements in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The objective is to extract the index number of a randomly selected grouped rows in Pandas.

Specifically, given a `df`

```
    nval
0      4
1      4
2      0
...
23     0
24     4
...
29     4
30     4
31     0
```

I would like to extract each 5 random index of the element 0 and 4.

For example, the 5 randomly selected value for

#### 0

can be

```
3,11,15,16,22
```

and

#### 4

can be

```
6 9 7 29 27
```

Currently, the code below answer the above objective

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
dval=[4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,
4,0,0,0,0,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,]

df = pd.DataFrame (dict(nval=dval))
cgroup=5
df=df.reset_index()
all_df=[]
for idx in [0,4]:
  x=df[df['nval']==idx].reset_index(drop=True)
  ids = np.random.choice(len(x), size=cgroup, replace=False).tolist()
  all_df.append(x.iloc[ids].reset_index(drop=True))

df=pd.concat(all_df).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(by=['index'])
sel_index=df[['index']]
```

Which produced

```
   index
0      3
1      6
2      7
3      9
4     11
5     15
6     16
7     22
8     27
9     29
```

However, I wonder there is compact way of doing this using pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
dval=[4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,4,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,0,]
df = pd.DataFrame (dict(nval=dval))

df2 = df.groupby('nval').sample(5).reset_index()
print(df2)
```

output:

```
   index  nval
0     31     0
1     22     0
2     14     0
3      8     0
4     17     0
5     29     4
6     13     4
7      1     4
8     19     4
9     12     4
```

Comment: Thanks for dropping by, this looks compact, but it only produce 1 index for the element `4`

Comment: @rpb the output is likely incorrect, the method is valid

Comment: I think it outputs two times 5 and it is only missing in the answer

Comment: sorry, I missed some output - edited it now.

Comment: Hi @jfaccioni, your suggestion works like a charm. But, if I change cgroup to 20, the compiler will return ValueError as expexted. Slightly greedy here, but just try my luck on requesting if it is possible if to allow the program take all index instead if cgroup is greater than what available in the group elements

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use

```
pd.DataFrame({'index': df.groupby('nval').sample(5).index.sort_values()})
```

I'd just keep the result as an index, so it simplifies to

```
df.groupby('nval').sample(5).index.sort_values()
```